# unique identifier for array of items in iphone

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I'm currently planning (and part coding) a new app. I have an array of items which the user creates. This is effectively the library. It's easiest to think of this as the classic ingredients and meal.

I have a library of ingredients. 
I then have a library of meals. 
Each meal will contain several ingredients.

So the relationship is one meal to many ingredients. Each ingredient can be used in multiple meals.
I am OK setting all this up - but I am having a think about how the ingredients will be identified within the meal. If I delete an ingredient, I then want to delete the reference in each meal where it may appear.

Should I be assigning a random ID (maybe a 5 digit number) for each ingredient the user creates, then when they add this to a meal, I use the 5 digit ID as the identifier. When a user deletes an ingredient, I then loop through each meal array and remove any references to the said ingredient 5 digit code.

OR... am I completely over thinking this?! 
Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do an: [item hash]

But...

It sounds like you want to just create an array of references from your "meals" to your "ingredients". An NSArray or NSMutableArray will retain your "ingredient" - and will release it when the array is released.

Comment: Thanks Brad. I've just been looking at the item hash. That seems to reference the array item memory if I'm right in thinking? You're right in saying that the meal array is simply a stack of references to the ingredients. NSMutableArray is the direction I was heading. Going to look at CFArray as I've never used them before. Thanks.

Comment: I'm a bit fuzzy - but I believe NSArray will simply RETAIN the object you place in it. (I originally thought NSArray would *copy* it, but I don't think that's the case).

Comment: NSArray does indeed retain its NSObjects.

Answer (score 1):

How about just using sqlite for storing both ingredients and meals? Don't know what you are actually coding, but it sounds like a good application for a database.

If you don't need to permanently store the data (e.g. you are actually talking about a game or something), you could still use a db with temporary tables).

Comment: Thanks Joseph. I have gone down the route of core data / SQLite before - but it's overkill for this. The application is a simple cooking app. I just need to store an ingredient's name and the cooking time. Then make up meals from those ingredients. I am probably going to simply make a NEW array of meals and copy the ingregients to that meal - but not the array item. Simply the contents and retain in the new. So it's not referenced. There will only ever be a handful of meals. Thanks for the reply.